# Find all consecutive sub-sequences of length n in a sequence

Tags: python, list

I want to find all consecutive sub-sequences of length n in a sequence.

E.g. say n was 3 and the sequence was:

```
[0,1,7,3,4,5,10]
```

I want a function that would produce as output:

```
[[0,1,7],[1,7,3],[7,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,10]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Seems to be quite straightforward actually. Iterate and take a subsequence of size n at each position.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> x = [0,1,7,3,4,5,10]
>>> n = 3
>>> zip(*(x[i:] for i in range(n)))
[(0, 1, 7), (1, 7, 3), (7, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 10)]
```

If you want the result to be a list of lists instead of list of tuples, use `map(list, zip(...))`.

Comment: Beautiful. Can you explain me what the * operator in the zip function does?

Comment: It unpacks a list .Useful if you are passing a list of arguments to a function , yet it expects a individual arguments

Comment: I know comments are supposed to be more constructive, but I simply found this beautiful.

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> x = [0,1,7,3,4,5,10]
>>> [x[n:n+3] for n in range(len(x)-2)]
[[0, 1, 7], [1, 7, 3], [7, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 10]]
```

Comment: To make this general for any subsequence size: `[x[i:i+n] for i in range(len(x)-n+1)]` where `n` is the desired length of the subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
def subseqs(seq, length):
    for i in xrange(len(seq) - length + 1):
        yield seq[i:i+length]
```

Use it ike this:

```
>>> for each in subseqs("hello", 3):
...     print each
...
hel
ell
llo
```

Of course it works also with lists:

```
>>> list(subseqs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3))
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might probably be suit for you:

```
def subseqs(xs, n):
  all_seqs = (xs[i:j+1] for i, _ in enumerate(xs) for j, _ in enumerate(xs))
  return filter(lambda seq: len(seq) == n, all_seqs)

>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # can be also range(1, 7) or list(range(1, 7)) 
>>> list(subseqs(xs, 3))
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Or simply, for getting all of the sequences of a list named 'xs':

```
[xs[i:j+1] for i, _ in enumerate(xs) for j, _ in enumerate(xs)]
```

For getting the sequences of a list named 'xs' that are only from length n:

```
[xs[i:j+1] for i, _ in enumerate(xs) for j, _ in enumerate(xs) if len(xs[i:j+1]) == n]
```