# Is there a way to use combinations() to return a list of [i]+[j] size permutations?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

For example:

```
list = [A,B,C,D]

print(combinations(list)
==============
[A]
[B]
[C]
[A,B]
[B,C]
[C,D]
[A,B,C]
[B,C,D]
[A,B,C,D]
```

I'm trying to print whatever is between i and j, so if i is the starting index, j is the length of the permutation (and sums up the elements within the permutation). What I don't want is a permutation like [A,B,D] (D is not next to the element B). Instead it should be [A,B,C].

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is all the possible subsequences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all consecutive sub-sequences of length n in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670828/find-all-consecutive-sub-sequences-of-length-n-in-a-sequence)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need combinations here. You just need to generate slices of increasing length, with incrementing start index:

```
​
def subsequences(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    for sub_length in range(1, length+1):
        for start in range(0, length - sub_length+1):
            yield lst[start:start+sub_length]


lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']                
print(list(subsequences(lst)))
```

Output:

```
[['a'],
 ['b'],
 ['c'],
 ['d'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['b', 'c'],
 ['c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't print the subsequences in the same order, but it does print all of them (and it uses `itertools.combinations`):

```
from itertools import combinations
def gen_subseq(a):
  return (a[i:j] for i, j in combinations(range(len(a)+1),2))
```

Testing:

```
>>> for s in gen_subseq(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']): print(s)
...
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['b']
['b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['c']
['c', 'd']
['d']
```

You can do this without `itertools.combinations`; doing the combinations yourself gives you more flexibility about the output order:

```py
def gen_subseq2(a):
   return (a[i:i+j+1] for j in range(len(a)) for i in range(len(a)-j))
```